# How can I allow the user input a # , which finds one of my local zip files with correct # and proceeds to download it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently creating a simple HTML page, that allows a user to input a "#", then with a click of a button, it will download the respective "#.zip".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<h2>Enter FileName # to start download...</h2>    
<input type="text" id="refID" title="Enter FileName # to start download">    
<button type= "file" onclick="Download()">Download</button>    
<script>
    function Download() {

      var x = document.createElement('a');
      var y = "ModifiedIndex/"+document.getElementById("refID").value+".zip";
      x.href = y;
    }
</script>
```

I expect a download to occur, but either the page will go blank, or it does nothing and stays on the page.

Comment: why do you need the user to input # ?

Comment: @axelaxel, I have another page that lists all the files and allows download directly from there but this is just for the scenario that my user knows exactly what file # they need and can get it easily,

Comment: shout out to Peter Smith, for fixing my horrible formatting !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that might be causing your page to go blank is `<button type="file">`. `type="file"` doesn’t exist, so it falls back to the default of submitting the form. (There isn’t one visible, but if the real code has one…) Use `type="button"`.

The thing that’s causing the download not to happen is that you’re creating a link, setting where the link goes to, and throwing the link away. Navigate to the URL instead:

```
function Download() {
  location.href = "ModifiedIndex/"+document.getElementById("refID").value+".zip";
}
```

Comment: its a button so he dosent even need the type

Comment: @axelaxel: The default is `type="submit"`. If it’s in a form, the type is necessary.